# Nodejs won't start on heroku after deploy

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, crash

I'm kind of noobie to NodeJs but I tried to publish an app that running locally to heroku.but it keeps throwing H10 errors after boot.

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secure-shelf-30086.herokuapp.com request_id=275885c2-48f1-410d-8651-e6aa4311f65b fwd="81.49.127.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=secure-shelf-30086.herokuapp.com request_id=f29afde7-6e30-4b7f-b22f-5b01599b6cdf fwd="81.49.127.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "App name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "App desc",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "v14.0.0",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/nickname/xxx-xxx.git"
  },
  "author": "nickname",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nickname/xxx-xxx/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/nickname/xxx--xxx#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "ent": "^2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "simple-ssh": "^1.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

The begining of my `app.js` file

```
var app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    ent = require('ent');

var SSH = require('simple-ssh');
```

Due to my research on other posts i added a `Procfile` entry in my repository like :

```
web:npm start
```

And there are my Config on my heroku app

```
NODE_ENV:           production npm start
NODE_MODULES_CACHE: false
```

Could it be due to missing favicon file ???

I'm all ears to find a way to run this app on heroku (I'm running it on a free plan)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you're using (process.env.PORT) beside your normal port number

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT }`);
});
```

Comment: At the end of my `app.js` file I have 
```server.listen(8080);```
Does it replace your code @sarkar ? Or do I need to write 
```server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);``` ?

Comment: @ThibaudRenaux yes because you're listen on port 8080 in your project but there is no guarantee that heroku use same port for your app so you need to write ``` server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080); ``` in order to use whatever port that heroku choose for you

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sarkar I succeeded in implementing your solution ! I need to keep in my all the gaps that could appear between local machine an production  one !

Comment: @ThibaudRenaux if this was your solution mark the answer as a correct answer